# Simple .c file fails to compile pthreads.h

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm a longtime python hobbyist porting a script over to c. I believe there is something wrong in the environment preventing the code from compiling. Research elsewhere leads me to believe it has something to do with posix header files? Maybe something with macros? I'm insufficiently experienced in c to figure it out.

The relevant snippet is here:

```
pthread_t id;
thread_create(&id, NULL, refreshqb,NULL);
void *status;
pthread_start(id, (void**)&status);
```

The error I receive is this.

```
t.c:91:4: warning: implicit declaration of function 'thread_create' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   thread_create(&id, NULL, refreshqb,NULL);
   ^
t.c:93:4: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pthread_start' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   pthread_start(id, (void**)&status);
   ^
2 warnings generated.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_pthread_start", referenced from:
      _main in t-0d3a02.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You already state `pthreads.h` but you do not seem to use it in your C file. That is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Support for pthreads must be explicitly enabled when compiling your code. It looks like you're using clang, so just add the `-pthread` flag when you compile using clang.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't try this yet. So "cc -pthread file.c" then.

Comment: @user2930324 yea! If that doesn't fix your problem, feel free to drop another comment and I can take another look

Answer (score 1):

Please try using pthread_create, along with including correct posix library header or  "#include <pthread.h>".

Comment: I did. The source file is much longer than I posted. I just included the relevant snippet.